# A proper way of handling audio I/O devices attache and detach on Mac

Tags: macos, audio, avfoundation

I have been looking for something similar for

```
AVCaptureDeviceWasConnectedNotification or AVCaptureDeviceWasDisconnectedNotification
```

but for audio playback and record device. I have done a quick google search, but I haven't found any quite relevant answer for this question. There is a sample code from Apple AVCaptureToAudioUnitOSX. but it does not handle multiple audio route.

I wonder if anyone has idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this at IOKit level by adding IOKit matching notifications for audio devices being hot-plugged or unplugged.  [Caveat - I've not done this in about a decade: higher level APIs might exist]

Apple's documentation for this is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_Finding_Devices/AH_Finding_Devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000379-BAJDAJDJ) - particularly the section

> Getting Notifications of Device Arrival and Departure

This is quite hard work. I advise you to get the IORegistryExplorer tool - which I believe is now in the Hardware IO Tools for Xcode download package (Xcode->Open Developer Tool->More Developer Tools).  You can use this to work out the matching criteria.